# How to properly identify an exception type in node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm getting an SSL error thrown by node. This is the exact line of code triggering it:

https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/tls.js#L201

I'm a novice to node and honestly I don't know how to correctly identify this SSL-specific error. In my code, I might look for the `Hostname/IP doesn't match certificate's altnames` string, but that looks very ugly.

Is there a better way to identify this error, other than looking for text in the error message?

Thanks!

Comment: What problem are you really trying to solve here?  If you're just trying to log or communicate what the problem is to some person, you can just communicate the error string directly without necessarily having the code know exactly which error it is.

Comment: I'm trying to identify the error and present it to the user as "SSL error".

Comment: Then, you can just see that the word "certificate" is in the error message and that will tell you it has something to do with an SSL Error.  I would suggest that when your users report they are getting "SSL Error" and you're tasked with figuring out what is wrong, you will wish you had more specific information than that.

Comment: Grepping the error message for specific string seems very ugly and fragile to me. Still, it might be the only way to do.

Comment: As you can see from the code, there is no other scheme.  It doesn't offer an error code or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the known error in a better way by create array of errors and that can also attached with the action need to be taken.

When you handle the exception / error, map them against the array you created using js prototypes and take necessary action.

Hope this will help. Thanks.

Updating...

```
var arrayOfErros = [
{error:"IP Error",action:"FunctionCall",Message:"You are getting IP Error"},
{error:"IP Error1",action:"FunctionCall1",Message:"You are getting IP Error1"}
]

try {
} catch(exp) {
   arrayOfErros.findError(exp,function(msg,action) {
     // do eval or show msg or any actions
  }); 
}

Array.findError(err, callback) {
 //run through array and return msg and action wn matches.
}
```

Comment: Sathik, I don't understand how this answers the question. The error is created by node itself. I'm trying to identify this specific error from my application code. What would this array of errors look like?

Comment: I don't think it really covers my case. Node is triggering an Error object with a variable message.

Comment: Yeap, get the error message and handle them. You can only know messages this way.